# How to show multiple results on google maps with same coordinates in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps

I stuck with showing multiple results on google maps. If my search results contains multiple markers on same location, there is only one accessible.
I'm using [google maps v3 api library](http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/)

Here is my code:

```
$n = 0;
        foreach ($firm as $f) {
            if ($f->active == 1 && in_array($f->skd_n, $dejavnost) && $f->lat != 0) {
                $lat_f = $f->lat;
                $lng_f = $f->lng;
                $distance = (($this->distance($lat, $lng, $lat_f, $lng_f)) * 1000);
                if ($distance <= $rad && $n <= 199) {
                    $marker = array();
                    $marker['position'] = "$lat_f, $lng_f";
                    if ($f->phone != 0) {
                        $marker['infowindow_content'] = '<div class="info_window">' . "$f->title" . '<br/>' .
                            '<div class="pin_icon"></div>' .
                            "$f->address" . '<br/>' .
                            '<div class="phone_icon"></div>' .
                            "$f->phone" . '<br/>' . '<hr>' .
                            '<div class="directions_icon"><a href="'.site_url()."domov/direction"."?lat=".$lat."&lng=".$lng."&lat_f=".$lat_f."&lng_f=".$lng_f.'" onClick="return popup(this)">Pokaži pot</a></div>' .
                            '<div class="street_view_icon"><a href="'.site_url()."domov/street_view"."?lat_f=".$lat_f."&lng_f=".$lng_f.'" onClick="return popup(this)">Street view</a></div>' .
                            '</div><br/>';

                    } else {
                        $marker['infowindow_content'] = '<div class="info_window">' . "$f->title" . '<br/>' .
                            '<div class="pin_icon"></div>' .
                            "$f->address" . '<br/>' . '<hr>' .
                            '<div class="directions_icon"><a href="'.site_url()."domov/direction"."?lat=".$lat."&lng=".$lng."&lat_f=".$lat_f."&lng_f=".$lng_f.'" onClick="return popup(this)">Pokaži pot</a></div>' .
                            '<div class="street_view_icon"><a href="'.site_url()."domov/street_view"."?lat_f=".$lat_f."&lng_f=".$lng_f.'" onClick="return popup(this)">Street view</a></div>' .
                            '</div>';
                    }
                    $marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
                    $marker['zIndex'] = '0';
                    $marker['icon'] = '../images/pin-map-red.png';
                    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
                    $n++;

                }
            }

        }
```

Try with location "ljubljana", "radij"- 10000 and chose "restavracije". Stronger shadow of marker means multiple results on same location and here i want to display all of them. How should i approach?
Here is [my page](http://www.grta-studio.com/diplomska/) to test my issue out

I'm thinking about setting a new value for coordinates in my database. For example, if i change longitude for 0.000014, i get result i wanted. Can you help me with query to change all duplicated coordinates (latitude and longitude) and set them like "if lat/lng have duplicated value, set lng+0.000014 for every next row".
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I decided to change my code to display multiple results. I don't how to display all titles of results with same $lat_f and $lng_f in 'infowindow_content' value.
Any suggestions?

```
$n = 0;
        foreach ($firm as $f) {
            if ($f->active == 1 && in_array($f->skd_n, $dejavnost) && $f->lat != 0) {
                $lat_f = $f->lat;
                $lng_f = $f->lng;
                $distance = (($this->distance($lat, $lng, $lat_f, $lng_f)) * 1000);
                if ($distance <= $rad && $n <= 199) {
                    $marker = array();
                    $marker['position'] = "$lat_f, $lng_f";
                    $marker['infowindow_content'] = "$f->title";
                    $marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
                    $marker['zIndex'] = '0';
                    $marker['icon'] = '../images/pin-map-red.png';
                    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
                    $n++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't know how your table structure looks like, you can filter out duplicated values in your database with this query

```
Select t1.id, t1.ColumnA, t1.ColumnB
From Table t1 
inner join Table t2 
on (t1.id <> i2.id AND t1.columnA = t2.columnA AND t1.columnB = t2.columnB)
```

Or this kind of query

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.COLUMN_A, t1.COLUMN_B
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.COLUMN_A = t2.COLUMN_A AND t1.COLUMN_B = t2.COLUMN_B
```

Once you have the rows you can change them manually in database or if there is too much data you should write a php script with some foreach loop and add desired value (0.000014) on desired field

Another way around your issue should be, to check if one marker can have multiple descriptions on it. If so the i would suggest to do so, and you don't have to make all those mysql and phpscript shenanigans.